# Android: how to fix CardViews' views scrolling in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I load a RecyclerView with CardViews that gets populated with some SQLite data and a checkbox.  The initial UI screen looks good with the CardViews:

[image]

I then begin scrolling downwards and a number of the CardViews disappear and the UI screen only shows one CardView.  If I scroll further then another single CardView shows for the entire screen rather than many CardViews that I expected:

[image]

What am I missing here?

```
DataModel.java file

public class DataModel implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String todo;
private String note1;
private boolean isSelected;

public DataModel() {
}

public DataModel(String todo, String note1) {
    this.todo = todo;
    this.note1 = note1;
    isSelected = false;
}

public DataModel(String todo, String note1, boolean isSelected) {
    this.todo = todo;
    this.note1 = note1;
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public String getTodo() {
    return todo;
}

public void setTodo(String todo) {
    this.todo = todo;
}

public String getNote1() {
    return note1;
}

public void setNote1(String note1) {
    this.note1 = note1;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
    this.isSelected = isSelected;
}
}

ListAdapter.java file

public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

List<DataModel> dbList = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dbList) {
    this.context =  context;
    this.dbList = dbList;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlecard_layout, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(itemView);
}

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView cardBlankText2;
    TextView cardBlankText3;
    CheckBox chkSelected;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardBlankText2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankText2);
        cardBlankText3 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankText3);
        chkSelected = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkSelected);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.cardBlankText2.setText(dbList.get(position).getTodo());
    holder.cardBlankText3.setText(dbList.get(position).getNote1());
    holder.chkSelected.setChecked(dbList.get(position).isSelected());
    holder.chkSelected.setTag(dbList.get(position));

    holder.chkSelected.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
            DataModel rowItem = (DataModel) cb.getTag();
            // rowItem.setSelected(cb.isChecked());
            dbList.get(position).setSelected(cb.isChecked());
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without code we can't help you, but let me assume, you are using `RecyclerView` new support `Library` which supports `wrap_content` and in your case, your layout list item height is set to `match_parent` try replacing your `cardview` parent `layout height` to `wrap_content`

Comment: Yes, I am using AppCompatActivity with appcompat-v7:23.3.0.  I will try wrap_content.

Comment: btw, how did you know the layout_height was set to match_parent?

Comment: It was obvious tho, since i faced this behavior when sometimes Android studio creates the xml layout by default as match_parent we weren't focus much because we know the item  will fit automatically, but now. U have to be aware of it, btw. If it did solve your issue you should accept the answer because trust me aloot more will come look for it :)

Comment: Nicely done, that did the trick.  I agree on Studio default.  Will accept and upvote answer.  Do you happen to know if I can use mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true) if I use the same size CardView for all CardViews?  There seems to be a lot of disagreement on SO about what exact layout this refers to.

Comment: you should follow up with the docs in the official doc:
`RecyclerView can perform several optimizations if it can know in advance that RecyclerView's size is not affected by the adapter contents.`
if you want to have fixed content size, as in your screens above you could do that easily by limiting your textview lines to 1 then all of them will follow one layout height, if this isn't an option for you then use GridLayoutManager as it is by default will make all your items have the exact same size

Comment: Got it, ok.  One more question please:  I have "android:scrollbars="vertical" set on the RecyclerView.  It shows properly for scrolling up and down with the CardViews on my Genymotion emulator.  But when I load on 2 different Samsung Galaxy phones, no vertical scrollbars show.  Would this problem be caused by an error with my padding or margin width settings?

Comment: After testing many options like recycledViewPool, it was simply to change my cardview from parent match to wrap content.
Thank you !!!